# is it possible to deploy a windows WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) application on linux server?

Tags: c#, linux, wpf, mono

I am new to c# and .net, I need to work on microsoft cognitive services https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services to build an customized api, just wondering if I can deploy that on linux server as all cognitive services are linux based wpf applications.

Comment: alternatives/anything easier than mono-project ?

Comment: I found,
https://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-on-linux/
Seems to be pretty common as a Google search. Also
https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/.

Comment: @DeclanCarroll The question is regarding WPF, not ASP.NET

Comment: @zillani Mono would be the best hope, but even Mono does not support WPF, only Silverlight and there are no plans to implement WPF support in Mono.

Comment: Got it, need to explore. Thanks @Glen Thomas